# Unity3d perform a callback from multiple scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lua, callback, coronasdk

I have a problem with callback function in C# script in Unity.

In Corona SDK if you want to perform a callback, you just need to pass it as an argument and then call it in proper place.

```
local function boom()
    print("booom!!!")
end

local function bang()
    print("baaaang!!!")
end

local function selector(var, func1, func2)
    if var > 0 then
        func1()
    else
        func2()
    end
end

selector(5, boom, bang)
selector(-12, boom, bang)
```

And I get:

```
booom!!!
baaaang!!!
```

Which is correct.

But when I try to implement it in C# script in Unity I have plenty of problems. First of all, passing just a parameter is not enough. You need to specify type of variable in `selector()` function. So I have to specify class name for `func1` and `func2`. But if I want to be able to call it from multiple scripts and pass different callback functions? Then I'm unable to specify class as a type.

I found few tutorials, but none of them solved my problem. They all describe how to do it within a class or only from a predefined class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it works quite similar in C#, except the fact that you have to be explicit about the types:

```
void boom()
{
    Debug.Log("booom");
}

void bang()
{
    Debug.Log("baaaang");
}

void selector(int v, Action func1, Action func2)
{
    if (v > 0)
        func1();
    else
        func2();
}

...

selector(5, boom, bang);
selector(-12, boom, bang);
```

Comment: It works! It really works! So "Action" was all about :D

Comment: BTW. How to set `Action func2` as optional? `Action? func2 = null` doesn't work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? It is usually helpful to give an error message or an explanation of the behaviour you judge to be non-functional. I suppose you get a NullReferenceException when trying to call func2(). That's to be expected, because you can't call null. Check if it is null before calling it, and only call it if it isn't.

Comment: Right. I thought it might be obvious to you. I got error message: "The type 'System.Action' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'". And I have `if (func2 != null) {func2 (); };` in first line of function, so I won't call null.

Comment: Oh of course. Action is already nullable because it is a reference type. So you don't need to make it nullable by appending a ``?``. Just say ``Action func2 = null`` to make it optional.

Comment: Hell yeah! Now it works like a charm! So what's the `?` usage rule? I thought I have to use it every time if "I'm not sure" I'll get an parameter for the variable.